# I want to understand Slick.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, slick.js

Trying to learn slick.js, jquery plugin for creating carousels/sliders.
But, while I was thinking that it is gonna be an easy-going solution for this common quest in web-dev, it is not, especially for the beginner like I am.

So, I have designed the environment like it was proposed in the slick docs here:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I want to make a carousel, like this one - for practice.
[Slider example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFrXD.png)

So, nothing special, 4 images in a row, scrolling 1-by-1, infinitely loop, with arrows on the left and on the right side of the slider.

Sounds pretty easy shot, as far as I could imagine reading the slick docs, but it is all contrary.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sl').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.main {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/themes/slick-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="sl">
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/slider-item1.png" alt="beige coat" class="slider__photo">
                <p class="slider__caption">Beige coat</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/slider-item2.png" alt="grey coat" class="slider__photo">
                <p class="slider__caption">Grey coat</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/slider-item3.png" alt="red coat" class="slider__photo">
                <p class="slider__caption">Red coat</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/slider-item4.png" alt="blue coat" class="slider__photo">
                <p class="slider__caption">Blue coat</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

End the result is like, this - no arrows whatsoever and other functionality...

When I set slidesToShow: 3, it gets some space and arrows emerge, but I can not understand its behaviour.

Can I get some guidance from you on this example to grasp the Slick logic?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery and check developer console